# Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string during Make

Tags: ruby, makefile

I am currently using a make file generated by create_makefile() module of mkmf. I have two doubts:

**1.** The paths generated in the make file are as /C/... and not C:/ as 
   expected by Windows. Is there any way of generating correct paths as 
   per Windows?

**2.** Contents of the makefile are:

```
   ruby:
        ruby -e "puts 'EXPORTS'"
```

When I run `[ruby -e "puts 'EXPORTS'"]` command from the prompt it 
   works. I also tried it on a Linux machine with Ruby version 1.8.6 and 
   the make runs without error. But when I run make on Windows, 
   Ruby version 1.9.3, it gives me below error:

```
 >make
    ruby -e "puts 'EXPORTS'"
    Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
    Makefile:2: recipe for target 'ruby' failed
    make: *** [ruby] Error 2
```

How can I fix this error? I see similar questions on StackOverflow but either the error is different or the questions are unanswered.

Comment: Check whether the line endings matter for your Windows `make`. Check that the editor hasn't switched your quotes for "smart quotes" as Windows is prone to do.

Comment: Did you tried using rake instead of make

Comment: This is likely related to the shell make uses on make, and which shell is being used depends on how make was created: cygwin make vs. mingw make.  If you use mingw make then the commands make invokes are being passed to the command.com, not a UNIX shell, and that handles command lines differently.

Comment: Thanks John! Yes, my editor was messing up my makefile. But the question still remains that mkmf is generating the makefile for me and how do I make it generate the correct paths (C:/ and not /C/) so that I do not have to manually edit the makefile later? I tried using both CYGWIN make and MINGW make.